# Gitignore is not untracking

Tags: git, github, version-control, push, gitignore

So, I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I can realize what.

My **.gitignore**: `{ content/data.db }`

When I change this document and I do `git status` I get:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    content/data.db
```

**Expected result**: Not track this file.

And, of course, if I do `git add -A && git commit -m"this is a test" && git push` the file is pushed to the repo.

I don't know what's wrong with `.gitignore`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to untrack the file, and then git will happily ignore it using the pattern in `.gitignore`. If a file is already being tracked, changes to it are not ignored even if it is in the ignorelist. From the current status, it is apparent that you have removed the file from your filesystem, but have not untracked it yet.

So, run the following:

```
git rm --cached content/data.db
git commit -m "removed db file"
```

In general, it is better to run your `git rm` commands with the `--cached` flag so that the local copies of the files do not get deleted.

Since, in your case, you already have the file in question deleted from the filesystem, `git rm content/data.db` will work all right as well.

***EDIT***

As discussed in comments below, check if your `.gitignore` has the entry as `{ content/data.db }`. Because that entry, with `{` and spaces  would become incorrect.

Just have a single line, with text `content/data.db` in your `.gitignore`. Make sure there are no redundant whitespace before or after the ignore rule.

The way git works, each complete line within `.gitignore` is treated as a pattern for `fnmatch`, and any redundant characters, like whitespaces or even comments beginning with `#` alter the pattern itself, causing the file to not be ignored.

Comment: No need for `--cached`; the output of `git status` indicates that the file has already been deleted from the file system.

Comment: @Jubobs yeah, but I always add that out of habit. Anyway, have added an explanation for it.

Comment: But, the trouble is ok the git status. I don't want to track it because it's in the .gitignore. But when I `git add -A` its included on the stage. Maybe I'm not explaining well enough.

Comment: @Bursos quick question, does your `.gitignore` have the entry as `{ content/data.db }`? Because that, with `{` and spaces ` ` would become incorrect. Just have a single line, with text `content/data.db` in it. Make sure there are no redundant whitespace before or after the ignore rule

Comment: You rock @mu無 ! If you create an answer with the solution of the brackets and whitespaces I'll accept it ;)
Nice catch!